# Float and double in C

Tags: c, floating-point

Is the output correct for the following programs? I am using a Cygwin64 GCC compiler on a X86_64 Windows system. The architecture is little endian.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    float floatVal = 0x12345678;
    do
    {
        printf("Hello World %f\n", floatVal);
        floatVal++;
        i++;
    } while ( i < 10 );
    return 0;
}

Hello World 305419904.000000
Hello World 305419904.000000
Hello World 305419904.000000
Hello World 305419904.000000
Hello World 305419904.000000
Hello World 305419904.000000
Hello World 305419904.000000
Hello World 305419904.000000
Hello World 305419904.000000
Hello World 305419904.000000
```

Question 1:
However this website gives me a completely different answer: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=12345678

Question 2:
Why is the value not incrementing? The increments happen however if I use double instead of float.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit, after getting the correct answers:

After getting the correct answers from unwind, I have a further question and to do the same in Java. Since Java, does not use unions, is there a way to do the conversion from integer to float the same way as the accepted answer in C. I found the answer here :

[How can I get/set individual bits in a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310491/how-can-i-get-set-individual-bits-in-a-float)

Comment: You're confused between the hex *value* of an integer literal (which gets converted to a float) and the hex *representation* of a float. `0x12345678` == `305419904`.

Answer (score 4):

You're expecting the integer literal (`0x12345678`) to be used to set the bits of the `float`, but that isn't what happens.

Instead you get the actual integer (`0x12345678` is `305419896` in decimal); your code is exactly the same as if it had said

```
float floatVal = 305419896;
```

The hexadecimal number is just an integer, that it's hex has no special meaning.

To do what you want, you'd to use an actual [hexadecimal float constant](http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/) perhaps, but that's a bit complicated.

You can use a `union` to the bits in there:

```
const union {
 int integer;
 float real;
} pair = { .integer = 0x12345678 };
float floatVal = pair.real;
```

Note that the above is undefined if the sizes mismatch, and also (as you seem to be aware) endian-specific.

If you print using `%e` or `%g` you will get the result you expect:

```
printf("%g\n", floatVal);
```

prints `5.69046e-28` on ideone.com.

Comment: That's undefined even if the sizes match.  There's no guarantee that you can reference an `int` as a `float` by casting the address.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks. Changed it to use a union instead which afaik should be OK.

Comment: @unwind can you please also write the answer when you print floatVal?

Comment: @unwind Using a union is also technically undefined behavior. The one and only standard-compliant way to reinterpret data like this is with `memcpy`.

Comment: @Sneftel Footnote 82 of C99TC3 makes using a union sound more like implementation-defined behavior, though.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you're confused between the hex *value* of an integer literal (which gets converted to a float) and the hex *representation* of a float. `0x12345678` == `305419904`.

As for the increment of a float using `++` seemingly not working as expected - this is simply due to the finite precision of a single precision floating point representation. If you start with a smaller number then you will see the expected behaviour:

```
 float f = 1.0f;  // f = 1.0
 f++;             // f = 2.0
```

However in your example:

```
 float f = 305419904.0f;  // f = 305419904.0
 f++;                     // f = 305419904.0
```

Note that using `double` will give the correct result for this case:

```
 double g = 305419904.0;  // g = 305419904.0
 g++;                     // g = 305419905.0
```